# How to store a double in vt M v product

Tags: c++, eigen

I am using Eigen library and I initialize a vector v (nx1) and a matrix M. I need to store the result of the product vt*M*v in a double variable, where vt is v.transpose(). How can I do that? thanks

Comment: Use an assignment statement

Answer (score 2):

```
Eigen::MatrixXd M(4,4);
M.setRandom();
Eigen::VectorXd v(4);
v.setRandom();
double output = v.transpose() * M * v;
std::cout << "M: " << M << std::endl;
std::cout << "v: " << v << std::endl;
std::cout << "output: " << output << std::endl;
```

result:
M:
-0.997497   0.170019    0.64568   0.421003
0.127171 -0.0402539    0.49321  0.0270699
-0.613392  -0.299417  -0.651784   -0.39201
 0.617481   0.791925   0.717887  -0.970031
v:
-0.817194,-0.271096,-0.705374,-0.668203
output: -0.435975